# How to install a Chrome extension with Python in all browser profiles? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

I need help. I understand that by default using the following code (using chromedriver and selenium) installs the extension but creates a temporary profile for each session.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('C:\\Usersers\\user\Desktop\Extension\Project\Extension.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:\Usersers.crx')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

**What I want is that I can install that extension in the profiles (if possible in all) that the browser has. And reading in the chromedriver website I found that, but I don't know how to implement it in the above code**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, it is not possible to install permanently extensions on the webdriver. You can only load and when the webdriver is killed, the extensions are gone.

If you need permanent extensions, you need to install them first on the profiles you need and then load the profile with

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/path/to/your/custom/profile");
```

The only solution I think it would work is to load the profile, and drive the browser to install the extension surfing on the chrome extension store and install it from there